# Cuda Fortran Device variable initialisation scope

Tags: cuda, fortran

If I create a variable in a subroutine to run on the device, is it local scope by default? and therefore only be accessed by each individual thread?

e.g would y in the following case be local scope?

```
module exampleMod
contains
  attributes(global) subroutine exampleSub(x)
    implicit none
    real :: x
    real :: y
  end subroutine exampleSub 
end module exampleMod
```

Would I need to additionally specify it as "device"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the absence of valid attribute (`shared` for example), any variable you declare within a `global` subroutine will have thread local scope.

Comment: Do you know any common reasons or bugs that cause variables in cuda fortran to suddenly switch to having a value of zero on the device?

Comment: No. If you have found a bug, make a demo case and report it to PGI